# Problems replicating Kover paper results

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to replicate the results for the creator of this repo:  https://github.com/aldro61/kover2_paper for genotype to phenotype machine learning interpretable (decision tree) prediction.

Specifically in the data section when I try to create the dataset as explained here:
https://github.com/aldro61/kover2_paper/tree/master/data

I make a directory called genomes_dir in the data directory. Then I do:

```
python download_genomes.py 'mycobacterium tuberculosis/kanamycin/metadata.tsv' genomes_dir
```

at the end of the download it tells me that it saved file `genome_paths.tsv` the data directory, not genomes_dir. So I run command:

```
kover dataset create from-tsv --genomic-data genome_paths.tsv ---phenotype-description "Kanamycin resistance" --phenotype-metadata 'mycobacterium tuberculosis/kanamycin/metadata.tsv  --output data_example.kover --progress
```

and it just hangs with a prompt:

```
(kover) nobu@gold3forever:~/Desktop/BioInformatics/ResearchAssistant/kover2_paper/data$ kover dataset create from-tsv --genomic-data genome_paths.tsv ---phenotype-description "Kanamycin resistance" --phenotype-metadata 'mycobacterium tuberculosis/kanamycin/metadata.tsv  --output data_example.kover --progress
> ^C
```

it does nothing after hours and hours so I control-C'd to end the process.

Does anyone have any idea what is happening?

I also had to install this to get the datasets from PATRIC:  https://github.com/aldro61/patric_tools

Answer (score 1):

The single quote at `'mycobacterium` is not matched so the command prompt is waiting indefinitely for the command to be completed. Maybe you want `'mycobacterium tuberculosis/kanamycin/metadata.tsv'` (note closing quote)

Comment: Thanks for the catch but now I'm getting some `kmer_count = get_kmer_count(tsv_path)
  File "/home/nobu/anaconda3/envs/kover/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kover/dataset/create.py", line 136, in get_kmer_count
    raise Exception()
Exception` so I'd better check the data I downloaded.